# Deep-Frying stuffed mushrooms?

Tags: deep-frying, mushrooms, raw-meat

I got stuffed mushrooms at the butcher's today with minced meat inside them. Would it be a good idea to deep-fry them; and if so on how many degrees would you do so?

Comment: They are almost certainly better baked than deep fried.

Comment: I'd never heard of deep fried stuffed mushrooms until recently. They were breaded before frying. I love deep fried mushrooms, but I've yet to try it deep frying them. As long as their breaded, I think they'd be excellent.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to fry them, you'd do well to coat them with breadcrumbs (using egg as an adhesive). Depending on the size of the mushrooms you may even need to do 2-3 layers.

If you don't coat them, they'll probably loose too much water and taste weird. I have deep fried coated muchrooms before (delicious!) at 170°C, however I never tried it with stuffed mushrooms. Personally I disliked them deep fried without coating, but I guess to each their own.